# MessageBox after typing in a recipient in outlook with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, message, inspector, mailitem

I would like to implement a window/message box that pops up in an outlook inspector once the sender has specified a recipient. How can I address outlook with Vsto that the message comes up before sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MailItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of an object is changed. You are interested in the `To`, `Cc` or `Bcc`  properties. Also you may find the [PropertyChange event and MailtItem Properties](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/417d026c-4486-4273-b346-94e20dad4796/propertychange-event-and-mailtitem-properties?forum=outlookdev) thread helpful.